# Check if a template parameter is some type of chrono::duration

Tags: c++, c++11

Given

```
template<class T>
struct TimeData
{
  T duration;
}
```

How can I write a `static_assert` to check in compile time if `T` is some type of `std::chrono::duration`? Remember `std::chrono::duration` is a template class.

In other words, how can I check if a type is some instantiation of a template class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can implement your own type trait to check for a `chrono::duration`. Something like this:

```
template<class T>
struct is_duration : std::false_type {};

template<class Rep, class Period>
struct is_duration<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>> : std::true_type {};
```

And then you can:

```
static_assert(is_duration<T>::value, "must be duration");
```